# When can "아/어서" mean "to"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I've found that "아/어서" can be used to mean "to" in a number of examples, such as:

> 저는 학교에 가서 공부할 거예요: I go to school to study

> 나는 친구들을 만나서 이야기했어요: I met my friends to talk

Now, I have 3 sentences as follows:

> 나는 한국어를 배우러 한국에 왔어요: I came to Korea to learn Korean.
>
> 나는 통역사가 되기 위해 한국어를 공부해요: I study Korean to become an interpreter
>
> 나는 운동하려고 일찍 일어나요:I get up early to exercise

Can I rewrite these 3 sentences as:

> 나는 한국에 와서 한국어를 공부할 거예요: I came to Korea to learn Korean.
>
> 나는 한국어를 공부해서 통역사가 될 거예요: I study Korean to become an interpreter
>
> 나는 일찍 일어나서 운동해요: I get up early to exercise

When can "아/어서" mean "to" ? Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, rewriting them that way would be correct.

Aside from the meaning of "Because", "아/어 사" Can be used in the following ways:

As a clause connector in which the second action occurs after the first (similar to 고). This is usually added to 오다 and 가다:

> 우리는 집에 와서 바로 잤어요: We came home and went to sleep immediately
>
> 저는 당근을 칼로 잘라서 냉장고에 넣었어요: I cut the carrots with the knife then put
> them in the fridge
>
> 새로운 컴퓨터를 사서 작업을 했어요: I bought a new computer, and then did my work (using that computer)

As a means to indicate that one action happens through the other:

> 저는 걸어서 집에 갔어요: I went home by walking (I walked home)
>
> 지구본을 사용해서 지도를 그렸어요: He used the globe to draw a map

This second case is where the meaning of "to" can be implied from 아/어서, however based on context, the same sentence can be interpreted using the first case.

Source: https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-3-intermediate-korean-grammar/lessons-67-75/lesson-70/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's misleading to ask when "아/어서" means "to" - they are both very versatile constructions that can be used in various situations.  So, some situations can be nicely expressed with "아/어서", some others with "to", and some others with both.

In the examples here, "A to B" can be interpreted as "A in order to do B".  "A-아서 B" can be interpreted as "A, and then (after that/as a result) B".  Given these definitions, one may say that the aren't the same at all - however, as shown in the question, there are sentences where both can be used naturally.

E.g., "저는 학교에 가서 공부할 거예요." would mean, "I will go to school, and (as a result of going to school) I will study."  But that's basically the same as "I am going to school to study."  Nobody would ask "Wait, is studying a mere byproduct of your arriving at the school or is it the original intention which prompted you to go to school?"  In most cases, that's a distinction without substance.

Similarly, "나는 친구들을 만나서 이야기했어요." means "I met my friends, and (as a result) I talked to them." which is the same as "I met my friends to talk." If you meet your friends, then of course you talk - nobody meets friends only to stare at each other.  So, again, they mean the same.

The reason why "to" is translated to "아/어서" here is because it's more natural in Korean.  If you say "나는 이야기하기 위해서 친구들을 만났어요." that sounds rather weird, as if you had a specific thing in mind that you must have told your friends.

Now let me examine your "transformed" sentences:

> 나는 한국에 와서 한국어를 공부할 거예요.

This sentence is wrong, because you're saying "I *will* come to Korea and study Korean," but if you're saying that then you aren't in Korea now, so you can't use "와서" - you have to use "가서".

Or you could say "나는 한국에 와서 한국어를 **공부했어요**" = I came to Korea and studied Korean.

Its meaning is a bit different from the original sentence, because the original sentence specified that the *reason* you came to Korea was to study Korean, but the new sentence made no such claim.  It's possible that you came to Korea for a job, and then you later decided you wanted to study Korean.

> 나는 한국어를 공부해서 통역사가 될 거예요. = I will study Korean and become a translator.

This sentence is similar to the original but there's a subtle difference.  The new sentence is more about your *resolve*: you decided that you will study Korean and become a translator.  In particular, you can say this sentence even if you didn't even start learning Korean.  (As of now, you just *want* to be a translator.)  The original sentence, of course, clearly means you are already studying Korean.

> 나는 일찍 일어나서 운동해요.

Hmm I think this one is pretty much the same as the original.  However, the original sentence is *explicit* that the reason you get up early is that you want to exercise.  It's merely implicit here.  For example, one can consider a contrived situation:

> A: 저는 일찍 일어나서 운동해요.  = I get up early and do exercise.
>
> B: 정말 운동을 좋아하시는군요!  = Wow, you must like exercises so much!
>
> A: 아니오, 아침마다 옆집 개가 짖어서 깨는데, 깨서 할 게 운동밖에 없어요.  = No, the neighbor's dog barks and wakes me up every morning, and there's nothing else for me to do once I wake up.